# What happens when storing a function's return type in a variable of a different type?

Tags: c, variables, type-conversion, return-type

For instance I call the function `round()` in C the manual says it returns a value of type `double`. I made an `int` variable in which I'm storing the result of this function. Everything seems to work perfectly fine, so my question is what happened here?

```
int rounded = round(cents);
```

Why does C even allow me to store the returned value of `rounds()` in a variable that is not of the same return type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C will automatically attempt a conversion from the return value of `round` (which is a `double`) to an `int`.

It *might* get converted.

Bear in mind that if the `double` returned is larger or smaller than that which can be held in an `int`, then the program behaviour is undefined.

You ought to compare with `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` before attempting the conversion.

Hopefully you can see now why `double` is, in fact, a sensible return type for `round`.

Answer (score 3):

in your question when you return a `double` value from `round()` to the main function, and assign it to a `int` variable. C converts `double` to `int` and then stores the returned value.
this kind of conversion is called **implicit conversion**... I've provided a link at the end, if you'd like to know more about it

**NOTE**: C doesn't store different data type but:

> 1) it converts the data to holding variable data type
>
> 2) and then stores it into the variable

you can know more about these kind of conversions... here: [conversions](http://clanguagebasics.com/c-language-tutorial/c-type-conversion-implicit-explicit-type-conversion-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

C does not do strong typing.

In general, when you use an object/a value of one numerical type where an object of a different numerical type is expected, C will automatically convert it.

This may fail (e.g. if the value is not representable) or may not be desired (and hopefully lead to a compiler warning then) but in most cases it is just convenient.